# SQL Server : add multiple rows in one sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-insert

I want to insert multiple rows in one query like this:

```
insert into EducationInfo (student_id, school_id)
values (
    (select id
     from STUDENT
     where iin in (select distinct iinplt
                   from TEST_STUDENT
                   where id_university = 9)), 23421
       )
```

Of course it is impossible. I know that I can do it like this:

```
 values(1,23421),
 values(2,23421)...
```

but as you can see I don't know ids from `student_id` column and there are too many ids. Is there any possible way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `insert . . . select`:

```
insert into nedb.EducationInfo (student_id, school_id)
     select id, 23421
     from nedb.student
     where iin in (select iinplt
                   from IMPORT_DATA.esuvo_students
                   where id_university = 9
                  );
```

Note that `select distinct` is unnecessary when using `in`.

Answer (score 1):

Use insert ... select ... join, that way you can manipulate your join to be something far more elaborate that just "in"

```
insert into nedb.EducationInfo (student_id, school_id)
 select distinct s.id, 23421
 from nedb.student s
 join (SELECT distinct iinplt FROM IMPORT_DATA.esuvo_students 
       WHERE id_university = 9 ) es ON s.iin = es.iinplt
```

make sure you don't have any many to many JOIN matches on your ON statement, otherwise it might slow the query down

Comment: Very nice solution! Thank you!